# jQuery AJAX mangling character enoding on the way to the server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I have looked through several question about AJAX and character encoding, but I can only seem to find questions about the response's encoding, but not where the data sent to the server's encoding.

I am sending a form serialized using jQuery to the server. PHP then saves this form's fields to a database. The database uses latin1-swedish-ci. The page with the form uses iso-8859-1.

When I do this by using AJAX to send the data to the server, characters like `“` get converted to `â€œ` on the way to the server, and get saved in the database as such. When I skip the AJAX and use a normal html form submit, the characters turn out fine in the database.

It is obvious that the jQuery serialization of the form data and the AJAX submission are what's causing the characters to get mangled, but how can I fix this? I have tried changing the contentType of the AJAX call. I have tried using `iconv()` to convert the characters server side, which causes errors or incorrect translations. I have tried to use `utf8_decode()` server side, but this converts it into a question mark. I cannot change the output pages to UTF-8 encoding, because this causes other problems with other content on these pages. Ideally the solution would prevent the characters from being saved in the database wrong in the first place, as would happen with a normal html form submit. Any ideas on how to solve this?

javascript that sends the form to the server:

```
BlogEditForm.prototype.save = function() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'blog_edit_ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: self.dialog.find( 'form' ).serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
            self.processSaveResponse.call( self, response );
        }
    } );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Javascript's encodeURIComponent() encode characters differently than an actual form submition. Ended up re-writing javascript encodeURIComponent function to solve this... Not the most performant solution, but no other solutions presented themselves:

```
var encodeURIComponent = ( function() {
    var encodeURIComponentOriginal = encodeURIComponent;
    return function ( input ) {
        var toReplace = [
            '%E2%80%9A',
            '%E2%80%A6',
            '%E2%80%98',
            '%E2%80%99',
            '%E2%80%9C',
            '%E2%80%9D',
            '%E2%80%93',
            '%E2%80%94',
            '%E2%84%A2',
            '%C2%A9',
            '%C2%AE',
        ];
        var replaceWith = [
            '%82', // ‚
            '%85', // …
            '%91', // '
            '%92', // '
            '%93', // "
            '%94', // "
            '%96', // –
            '%97', // —
            '%99', // ™
            '%A9', // ©
            '%AE', // ®
        ];               

        var output = encodeURIComponentOriginal( input );

        var length = toReplace.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            var regexp = new RegExp( toReplace[i], 'g' );
            output = output.replace( regexp , replaceWith[i] );
        } 

        return output;
    };
} )();
```

Comment: from @PeterDobbs, a link with all the URI encodings: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried parsing the serialized bit in to a string in your `PHP` before saving it to the database?

```
parse_str($_POST['field_name'], $php_variable_name);
```

and use `$php_variable_name` in your insert query?

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: parse_str() parses a query string into individual fields. it does not parse an individual field into anything. i'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in your suggestion. it doesn't seem to make sense. my code already has the query string parsed.

Answer (score 1):

This seams to be a general issue with jQuery's serialize() method.

There's an article that suggests a solution, but make sure to read the comments.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/serialize-problem-with-latin-1-iso-8859-1-and-solution

Comment: I tried adding this code to my jQuery, along with the "+" fixing regex in the comments. This now turns my `“` characters into `%u201C`. It does sound like the same issue as what I am experiencing... I copied the code precisely, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Perhaps this is for an older version of jQuery? I am using the latest version myself.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery internally uses encodeURIComponent, all data is transferred in UTF-8 anyway.
Try again the iconv, but with the UTF-8 converter.

```
$f = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $_POST['f']);
```

Note that MySql does another conversion for all passed data.

Comment: Doing this cuts the string to only what content is before the first `“` character. Everything after that character disappears.

Comment: After further investigation, it seems that this causes an error saying that there are invalid characters in the input string.

Comment: instead of ISO-8859-1 try to use the encoding from plain form post headers.
And post a raw string that is beeing sent, here in comments.

Comment: If I send using an HTML submit, the raw post data for that character is `%93`

Comment: Using serialize and ajax, the raw post data for that character is `%E2%80%9C`